# Upgrading MongoEngine Document and Embedded Document Schemas

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm wondering if there is a good way to upgrade the schemas in my rigid document/embedded document schemas in Mongoengine 0.9.0 and Mongo 3.0.

I have the most problems with embedded documents, getting the FieldDoesNotExist exception when removing fields from the schema.

mongoengine.errors.FieldDoesNotExist

I have been trying to use _mark_as_changed('field_name') but does not function as I want with embedded documents.

```
for user in User.objects:
        user.embedded._mark_as_changed('number')
        user.embedded._mark_as_changed('name')
        user.save()
```

Thanks!